# VueJS: Watching Vuex getter in multiple components not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I have a Vuex state `processState` that has below getter

```
export const getters = {
  getProcessState: state => {
    return state.processState;
}
```

I am watching this getter in two different components like below

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

 export default {
   computed: {
     ...mapGetters("process/processStore", ["getProcessState"])
   },
   watch: {
     getProcessState(newVal, oldVal) {
       //different logic for each component.
     }
   }
};
</script>
```

Now when `processState` changes, `getProcessState(newVal, oldVal)` in only one component is invoked. If I comment out the watch in the component in which it is invoked the other one starts working. So at one time only one is working. Is there something about `Vuex` or `watch` I am missing that is causing this problem?

Thanks

**Update**
I tried watching the `getter` in a third component. but it is not also invoked.

Comment: One watch shouldn't prevent another.  Also there's no need for a getter when returning a single state item.  It would be the equivalent of having a computed to return a component data item.

Comment: @Dan ideally it shouldn't. But it is not working with `mapState` either.  And the code is similar in both components for watching the state.

Comment: I agree with Dan, that if that is the actual getter, couldn't you delete it and just reference the state directly, either with `mapState()` or `this.$store.state.processState`? Still, that is weird that not all the watchers are being called

Comment: @JoeDalton I can take that suggestion but apparently mapping state directly is also not working.

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Ok. What kind of data is processState? If you're mutating properties on an object, and not replacing the whole object, are you using Vue.set()?

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary Could you try removing all the logic from the `watch` functions and confirm that you see the same problem when they just contain a single line of logging? While it is unlikely, it is possible that the logic in one watcher is making changes that prevent the other watchers from running, e.g. by resetting the value of `processState` so it hasn't changed from the perspective of other watchers.

Comment: The behavior you are experiencing should not happen. This is impossible to diagnose without a reproducible example.

Answer (score 3):

If you getters is not returning a scalar (i.e. if it is returning an Object {} or array []), you have to watch it like so:

```
watch: {
  getProcessState: {
    deep: true,
    handler: function(newVal, oldVa) {
     // Your logic
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try directly using the `getter` without mapping

```
    watch: {
        '$store.getters.getProcessState': function (value) {
            // your logic
        }
    }
```